# What is a diameter of smaller circle?

Tags: geometry, circles

I have two coins $A$ and $B$. The diameter of coins A is $d_A=18$ mm. The smaller coin $B$ rolls around $A$ without sliding. Both coins have marks on the edge. At the beginning of the movement, the coins touch the marks (see the figure).

[image]

To make the labels match again the first time, coin B should make two turns around $A$.

**Question.** What can be the diameter of coin $B$, $d_B$?

**My attempt.** The length of the circumference $C_A$ is related to the diameter $d_A$ by: $C_A=\pi d_A$, and the length of the circumference $C_B$ is $C_B=\pi d_B$. We know that $2 C_B = C_A$, therefore, $C_B =\frac{ C_A}{2}$, next $\pi d_B = \pi \frac{d_A}{2}$, $d_B = \frac{d_A}{2}=18/2=9$mm.

But correct answer is $12$ mm. Where is my error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$12$mm is just one possible answer. What we need is that $B$ makes an odd number of revolutions while circling $A$ twice. So this would mean that twice the circumference of $A$ will be $k$ times the circumference of $B$, where $k$ is odd (to avoid matching on the first time around).

So the options are that $B$ has $\frac 23, \frac 25, \frac 27, \frac 29$ etc. of the circumference of $A$, and hence also the same proportion of the diameter.

For an integer mm diameter for $B$, we have the options of $\frac 23\times 18=12$mm and $\frac 29\times 18=4$mm.

Answer (score 2):

If $2C_B=C_A$, then $B$ would have to go around $A$ just one time to 'match up'!